# Go unmarshal nested arrays with identical name but separate elements

Tags: xml, go

I have a problem where an API returns two nested XML arrays in a response both with the name `rowset` but different elements. Trying to unmarshal into a struct causes the error `field "Attackers" with tag "rowset>row" conflicts with field "Items" with tag "rowset>row"`.

They both have an attribute `name` which are unique. Is it possible to influence the parser with this attribute?

See example: https://play.golang.org/p/BinDfC3XsW

Comment: Have you consider to declare a struct that resemble the XML structure, then you convert that into your KillMailsXML struct? After reading the documentation, I don't think you can specify an element based on its attribute. Better to have Attackers and Items in the same field, then write a converter that translates it correctly

Comment: Probably something like [this](https://play.golang.org/p/yAkpMaZ2RW), then convert the result to the structure you wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't change the structure of `xml` data, then defer unmarshaling `rowset` with the following steps (Working example can be found at [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-aNl1WvMjJ)):

1. Unmarshal elements except `rowset` which are related to `victim`. During this step, the `rowset` will be unmarshaled into raw XML data.
2. Decode raw XML separately using `Decoder.DecodeElement`.

First declare the data structure as follows (declaration of `Victim`, `Attacker`, `Item` is omitted):

```
type Kill struct{
    // Generic kill information
    KillID              int64      `xml:"killID,attr"`
    Hash                string
    SolarSystemID       int64      `xml:"solarSystemID,attr"`
    MoonID              int64      `xml:"moonID,attr"`
    // Victim Information
    Victim              Victim     `xml:"victim"`      
    RawAttackersItems   []byte     `xml:",innerxml" json:"-"`
    Attackers           []Attacker `xml:"-"`
    Items               []Item     `xml:"-"`        
} 

type Kills struct {
    Kills []Kill `xml:"result>rowset>row"`
}
```

Next, code lines for unmarshaling the xml:

```
//Step (1). Unmarshal to Kills
v := &Kills{}
if err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(xmlText()), v); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Error unmarshaling: %v\n", err)
    return
}

//Step (2). Decode attackers and items related to victim
for i, k := range v.Kills {   
    v.Kills[i].Attackers, v.Kills[i].Items = decodeAttackerAndItems(k.RawAttackersItems)
}
```

and finally the decoder function:

```
func decodeAttackerAndItems(data []byte) ([]Attacker, []Item) {
    xmlReader := bytes.NewReader(data)
    decoder := xml.NewDecoder(xmlReader)

    const (
        unknown int = iota
        attackers
        items
    )    
    rowset := unknown

    attackerList := []Attacker{}
    itemList := []Item{}

    for {
        t, _ := decoder.Token() 
        if t == nil { 
            break 
        } 

        switch se := t.(type) { 
        case xml.StartElement: 
            if se.Name.Local == "rowset" {
                rowset = unknown
                for _, attr := range se.Attr {
                    if attr.Name.Local == "name" {
                        if attr.Value == "attackers" {
                            rowset = attackers
                            break
                        } else if attr.Value == "items" {
                            rowset = items
                            break
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if se.Name.Local == "row" {
                switch rowset {
                case attackers:
                    a := Attacker{}
                    if err := decoder.DecodeElement(&a, &se); err == nil {
                        attackerList = append(attackerList, a)
                    }
                case items:
                    it := Item{}
                    if err := decoder.DecodeElement(&it, &se); err == nil {
                        itemList = append(itemList, it)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return attackerList, itemList
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works fine, try it on [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-hViom7Bum):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var v *KillMailsXML
    if err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &v); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for _, ks := range v.Kills {
        for _, rs := range ks.Rowsets {
            fmt.Println(rs.Who, rs.Rows)
        }
    }
}

type KillMailsXML struct {
    Kills []struct {
        // Generic kill information
        KillID        int64 `xml:"killID,attr"`
        Hash          string
        SolarSystemID int64 `xml:"solarSystemID,attr"`
        MoonID        int64 `xml:"moonID,attr"`

        // Victim Information
        Victim struct {
            AllianceID      int64   `xml:"allianceID,attr"`
            AllianceName    string  `xml:"allianceName,attr"`
            CharacterID     int64   `xml:"characterID,attr"`
            CharacterName   string  `xml:"characterName,attr"`
            CorporationID   int64   `xml:"corporationID,attr"`
            CorporationName string  `xml:"corporationName,attr"`
            DamageTaken     int64   `xml:"damageTaken,attr"`
            FactionID       int64   `xml:"factionID,attr"`
            FactionName     string  `xml:"factionName,attr"`
            ShipTypeID      int64   `xml:"shipTypeID,attr"`
            X               float64 `xml:"x,attr"`
            Y               float64 `xml:"y,attr"`
            Z               float64 `xml:"z,attr"`
        } `xml:"victim"`
        Rowsets []struct {
            Who  string `xml:"name,attr"` // Attackers or Items
            Rows []struct {
                //              Attackers struct {
                AllianceID      int64   `xml:"allianceID,attr"`
                AllianceName    string  `xml:"allianceName,attr"`
                CharacterID     int64   `xml:"characterID,attr"`
                CharacterName   string  `xml:"characterName,attr"`
                CorporationID   int64   `xml:"corporationID,attr"`
                CorporationName string  `xml:"corporationName,attr"`
                DamageDone      int64   `xml:"damageDone,attr"`
                FactionID       int64   `xml:"factionID,attr"`
                FactionName     string  `xml:"factionName,attr"`
                FinalBlow       bool    `xml:"finalBlow,attr"`
                SecurityStatus  float64 `xml:"securityStatus,attr"`
                ShipTypeID      int64   `xml:"shipTypeID,attr"`
                WeaponTypeID    int64   `xml:"weaponTypeID,attr"`
                //              }
                //              Items struct {
                QtyDestroyed int64 `xml:"qtyDestroyed,attr"`
                QtyDropped   int64 `xml:"qtyDropped,attr"`
                TypeID       int64 `xml:"typeID,attr"`
                Flag         int64 `xml:"flag,attr"`
                Singleton    int64 `xml:"singleton,attr"`
                //              }
            } `xml:"row"`
        } `xml:"rowset"`
    } `xml:"result>rowset>row"`
}

var str = `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<eveapi version="2">
  <currentTime>2016-07-06 05:49:28</currentTime>
  <result>
    <rowset name="kills" key="killID" columns="killID,solarSystemID,killTime,moonID">
      <row killID="54933226" solarSystemID="31001222" killTime="2016-07-03 22:29:19" moonID="0">
        <victim characterID="93811169" characterName="Madcat326" corporationID="98008818" corporationName="Haight Industries LLC" allianceID="0" allianceName="" factionID="0" factionName="" damageTaken="63039" shipTypeID="17918" x="59788513854.179" y="-13687850177.3741" z="157817245029.115" />
        <rowset name="attackers" columns="characterID,characterName,corporationID,corporationName,allianceID,allianceName,factionID,factionName,securityStatus,damageDone,finalBlow,weaponTypeID,shipTypeID">
          <row characterID="91316135" characterName="Celeo Servasse" corporationID="98134538" corporationName="Wormbro" allianceID="0" allianceName="" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="-1.0646369409683" damageDone="7825" finalBlow="1" weaponTypeID="3520" shipTypeID="12003" />
          <row characterID="95273329" characterName="Mupoc Kashuken" corporationID="98134538" corporationName="Wormbro" allianceID="0" allianceName="" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="-0.2" damageDone="16656" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="31882" shipTypeID="12023" />
          <row characterID="94389072" characterName="Johanis Cal-dahari" corporationID="98134538" corporationName="Wormbro" allianceID="0" allianceName="" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="2" damageDone="11999" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="24486" shipTypeID="29986" />
          <row characterID="92090484" characterName="Foxstar Damaskeenus" corporationID="98134538" corporationName="Wormbro" allianceID="0" allianceName="" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="-0.4" damageDone="10383" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="22444" shipTypeID="22444" />
          <row characterID="95708401" characterName="Bibet Shakure" corporationID="98134538" corporationName="Wormbro" allianceID="0" allianceName="" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="-1.3" damageDone="6928" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="24490" shipTypeID="29986" />
          <row characterID="0" characterName="" corporationID="500020" corporationName="Serpentis" allianceID="0" allianceName="" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="0" damageDone="3903" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="0" shipTypeID="38659" />
          <row characterID="96420826" characterName="D Joker" corporationID="98134538" corporationName="Wormbro" allianceID="0" allianceName="" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="0" damageDone="2858" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="2488" shipTypeID="33470" />
          <row characterID="0" characterName="" corporationID="500011" corporationName="Angel Cartel" allianceID="0" allianceName="" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="0" damageDone="2487" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="0" shipTypeID="42127" />
          <row characterID="94791823" characterName="chaosInjection" corporationID="98134538" corporationName="Wormbro" allianceID="0" allianceName="" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="-1" damageDone="0" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="12267" shipTypeID="29986" />
          <row characterID="90957994" characterName="Conner Asanari" corporationID="98134538" corporationName="Wormbro" allianceID="0" allianceName="" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="0.5" damageDone="0" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="16521" shipTypeID="22452" />
        </rowset>
        <rowset name="items" columns="typeID,flag,qtyDropped,qtyDestroyed,singleton">
          <row typeID="394" flag="20" qtyDropped="1" qtyDestroyed="0" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="24427" flag="32" qtyDropped="0" qtyDestroyed="1" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="2446" flag="87" qtyDropped="1" qtyDestroyed="1" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="28209" flag="87" qtyDropped="2" qtyDestroyed="0" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="4405" flag="15" qtyDropped="1" qtyDestroyed="0" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="33450" flag="27" qtyDropped="0" qtyDestroyed="1" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="19215" flag="23" qtyDropped="0" qtyDestroyed="1" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="2456" flag="87" qtyDropped="5" qtyDestroyed="0" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="26448" flag="93" qtyDropped="0" qtyDestroyed="1" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="33450" flag="28" qtyDropped="0" qtyDestroyed="1" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="394" flag="24" qtyDropped="0" qtyDestroyed="1" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="394" flag="21" qtyDropped="0" qtyDestroyed="1" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="19215" flag="19" qtyDropped="0" qtyDestroyed="1" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="4405" flag="14" qtyDropped="1" qtyDestroyed="0" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="1422" flag="12" qtyDropped="1" qtyDestroyed="0" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="2048" flag="16" qtyDropped="1" qtyDestroyed="0" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="26448" flag="94" qtyDropped="0" qtyDestroyed="1" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="33450" flag="29" qtyDropped="0" qtyDestroyed="1" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="33450" flag="30" qtyDropped="1" qtyDestroyed="0" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="2629" flag="5" qtyDropped="1750" qtyDestroyed="0" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="33450" flag="31" qtyDropped="0" qtyDestroyed="1" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="2281" flag="22" qtyDropped="1" qtyDestroyed="0" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="19241" flag="25" qtyDropped="0" qtyDestroyed="1" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="1422" flag="13" qtyDropped="0" qtyDestroyed="1" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="26448" flag="92" qtyDropped="0" qtyDestroyed="1" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="1422" flag="11" qtyDropped="0" qtyDestroyed="1" singleton="0" />
        </rowset>
      </row>
      <row killID="54868503" solarSystemID="31000868" killTime="2016-06-30 03:39:22" moonID="0">
        <victim characterID="91316135" characterName="Celeo Servasse" corporationID="98134538" corporationName="Wormbro" allianceID="0" allianceName="" factionID="0" factionName="" damageTaken="18472" shipTypeID="11987" x="685670430496.578" y="-376814977944.382" z="-365907110851.975" />
        <rowset name="attackers" columns="characterID,characterName,corporationID,corporationName,allianceID,allianceName,factionID,factionName,securityStatus,damageDone,finalBlow,weaponTypeID,shipTypeID">
          <row characterID="641035756" characterName="Lenex Raay" corporationID="98040755" corporationName="Hard Knocks Inc." allianceID="99005065" allianceName="Hard Knocks Citizens" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="5.00297218487895" damageDone="1169" finalBlow="1" weaponTypeID="2969" shipTypeID="22444" />
          <row characterID="1817541889" characterName="gr33nCO" corporationID="98040755" corporationName="Hard Knocks Inc." allianceID="99005065" allianceName="Hard Knocks Citizens" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="-0.1" damageDone="2163" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="2456" shipTypeID="22444" />
          <row characterID="92060039" characterName="Braxus Deninard" corporationID="98040755" corporationName="Hard Knocks Inc." allianceID="99005065" allianceName="Hard Knocks Citizens" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="-0.7" damageDone="1770" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="2488" shipTypeID="22444" />
          <row characterID="1734877398" characterName="Pantuf" corporationID="98040755" corporationName="Hard Knocks Inc." allianceID="99005065" allianceName="Hard Knocks Citizens" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="4.9" damageDone="1681" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="2456" shipTypeID="22444" />
          <row characterID="92941592" characterName="Foedus Latro" corporationID="98040755" corporationName="Hard Knocks Inc." allianceID="99005065" allianceName="Hard Knocks Citizens" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="-1.2" damageDone="1663" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="22444" shipTypeID="22444" />
          <row characterID="782985098" characterName="AwingendeR" corporationID="98040755" corporationName="Hard Knocks Inc." allianceID="99005065" allianceName="Hard Knocks Citizens" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="1.9" damageDone="1501" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="2488" shipTypeID="22444" />
          <row characterID="93802816" characterName="Tycho Loor" corporationID="98040755" corporationName="Hard Knocks Inc." allianceID="99005065" allianceName="Hard Knocks Citizens" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="-1.9" damageDone="1405" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="22444" shipTypeID="22444" />
          <row characterID="91004291" characterName="Broxis Khoros" corporationID="98040755" corporationName="Hard Knocks Inc." allianceID="99005065" allianceName="Hard Knocks Citizens" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="-1.8" damageDone="1228" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="2488" shipTypeID="22444" />
          <row characterID="92007576" characterName="Dean Mintar" corporationID="98040755" corporationName="Hard Knocks Inc." allianceID="99005065" allianceName="Hard Knocks Citizens" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="3.1" damageDone="1057" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="2488" shipTypeID="22444" />
          <row characterID="91702100" characterName="EMU EVIL" corporationID="98040755" corporationName="Hard Knocks Inc." allianceID="99005065" allianceName="Hard Knocks Citizens" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="-1.4" damageDone="792" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="2488" shipTypeID="11978" />
          <row characterID="95430803" characterName="Violet Dawn" corporationID="98040755" corporationName="Hard Knocks Inc." allianceID="99005065" allianceName="Hard Knocks Citizens" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="1" damageDone="789" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="2488" shipTypeID="33157" />
          <row characterID="647412341" characterName="Lysus" corporationID="98040755" corporationName="Hard Knocks Inc." allianceID="99005065" allianceName="Hard Knocks Citizens" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="-2" damageDone="761" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="22444" shipTypeID="22444" />
          <row characterID="91986431" characterName="sHanQ Myteia" corporationID="98040755" corporationName="Hard Knocks Inc." allianceID="99005065" allianceName="Hard Knocks Citizens" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="-1" damageDone="497" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="2456" shipTypeID="11963" />
          <row characterID="90571681" characterName="Pyrric Skloric" corporationID="98040755" corporationName="Hard Knocks Inc." allianceID="99005065" allianceName="Hard Knocks Citizens" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="0.1" damageDone="356" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="2488" shipTypeID="22444" />
          <row characterID="964223112" characterName="Tisisan" corporationID="98040755" corporationName="Hard Knocks Inc." allianceID="99005065" allianceName="Hard Knocks Citizens" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="0.9" damageDone="313" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="2488" shipTypeID="22444" />
          <row characterID="1039287135" characterName="J3rz11" corporationID="98040755" corporationName="Hard Knocks Inc." allianceID="99005065" allianceName="Hard Knocks Citizens" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="0.4" damageDone="265" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="2488" shipTypeID="22444" />
          <row characterID="91343130" characterName="Sophia Utama" corporationID="98040755" corporationName="Hard Knocks Inc." allianceID="99005065" allianceName="Hard Knocks Citizens" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="0.6" damageDone="237" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="22444" shipTypeID="22444" />
          <row characterID="94149890" characterName="Minnie Sodom" corporationID="98040755" corporationName="Hard Knocks Inc." allianceID="99005065" allianceName="Hard Knocks Citizens" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="2.6" damageDone="225" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="2488" shipTypeID="11978" />
          <row characterID="91875279" characterName="Derek Itinen" corporationID="98040755" corporationName="Hard Knocks Inc." allianceID="99005065" allianceName="Hard Knocks Citizens" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="0.8" damageDone="210" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="2488" shipTypeID="11978" />
          <row characterID="1556079273" characterName="Alita Hayes" corporationID="98040755" corporationName="Hard Knocks Inc." allianceID="99005065" allianceName="Hard Knocks Citizens" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="-0.1" damageDone="186" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="22444" shipTypeID="22444" />
          <row characterID="2086742079" characterName="Turd Destroyer" corporationID="98040755" corporationName="Hard Knocks Inc." allianceID="99005065" allianceName="Hard Knocks Citizens" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="3.3" damageDone="115" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="22444" shipTypeID="22444" />
          <row characterID="91044028" characterName="Viktoria Bernhardt" corporationID="98040755" corporationName="Hard Knocks Inc." allianceID="99005065" allianceName="Hard Knocks Citizens" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="2.8" damageDone="89" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="28215" shipTypeID="11978" />
          <row characterID="941167595" characterName="Justin Cody" corporationID="98040755" corporationName="Hard Knocks Inc." allianceID="99005065" allianceName="Hard Knocks Citizens" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="1.6" damageDone="0" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="15891" shipTypeID="11969" />
          <row characterID="686125406" characterName="NoobMan" corporationID="98040755" corporationName="Hard Knocks Inc." allianceID="99005065" allianceName="Hard Knocks Citizens" factionID="0" factionName="" securityStatus="-0.1" damageDone="0" finalBlow="0" weaponTypeID="2873" shipTypeID="11186" />
        </rowset>
        <rowset name="items" columns="typeID,flag,qtyDropped,qtyDestroyed,singleton">
          <row typeID="16455" flag="30" qtyDropped="1" qtyDestroyed="0" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="16455" flag="28" qtyDropped="0" qtyDestroyed="1" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="31366" flag="92" qtyDropped="0" qtyDestroyed="1" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="16487" flag="32" qtyDropped="1" qtyDestroyed="0" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="6005" flag="19" qtyDropped="1" qtyDestroyed="0" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="16487" flag="31" qtyDropped="1" qtyDestroyed="0" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="29011" flag="5" qtyDropped="0" qtyDestroyed="1" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="31366" flag="93" qtyDropped="0" qtyDestroyed="1" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="29009" flag="5" qtyDropped="1" qtyDestroyed="0" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="13970" flag="11" qtyDropped="1" qtyDestroyed="0" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="13982" flag="12" qtyDropped="1" qtyDestroyed="0" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="2048" flag="14" qtyDropped="1" qtyDestroyed="0" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="18712" flag="13" qtyDropped="0" qtyDestroyed="1" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="20353" flag="15" qtyDropped="0" qtyDestroyed="1" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="16455" flag="27" qtyDropped="1" qtyDestroyed="0" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="16455" flag="29" qtyDropped="0" qtyDestroyed="1" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="2488" flag="87" qtyDropped="0" qtyDestroyed="1" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="41155" flag="20" qtyDropped="0" qtyDestroyed="1" singleton="0" />
          <row typeID="1952" flag="20" qtyDropped="1" qtyDestroyed="0" singleton="0" />
        </rowset>
      </row>
    </rowset>
  </result>
  <cachedUntil>2016-07-06 06:16:28</cachedUntil>
</eveapi>`
```